# How to remove the baseline of sensor output?

Tags: amplifier, sensor, adc, signal-processing

In my project I am using a CO2 sensor that output voltage in range 30mV ~ 50mV. The signal will then be amplified and filtered and be sent to a microcontroller for ADC.

My tutor suggested that I should get rid of the baseline (30mV) and only amplify the difference (50mV - 30mV = 20mV). But I can't think of a way to remove the baseline with electronic circuit.

Can anyone give me a hint or a reference to read so I can achieve this?

Comment: Summing amplifier (opamp)

Comment: It's much more complicated if your baseline varies with an independent variable, e.g. temperature.

Comment: Google common mode rejection and running an up amp as a differential amp. Consider just capturing the signal in digital and use centering and running average to handle latent covariances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to subtract the same value just use an op-amp and 4 resistors as a difference amplifier.  If you want more precision you can buy difference amplifier chips with well matched resistors inside it already.  An instrumentation amplifier could also be a good choice here because it will have high input impedance.

Put your sensor on the non-inverting side of the instrumentation amplifier.  Attach a 30mV reference to the inverting input of the instrumentation amplifier.

You will probably have to construct the 30mV reference from a 1.25V reference and a voltage divider.  If you need to make the 30mV offset adjustable then use a potentiometer instead of a fixed divider.